# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null (Search Bar)

Tags: javascript, search, null

I'm trying to get the word I write in my searchbar to appear on the console, but it always seems to be 'null'. I looked through the other answers and it always seemed like it was an "onload" issue, which I don't believe I have since inside my html, I have a 'onload' for the body, which does my setup.

The setup does stuff Firebase related, but when I uncomment the "btn.onclick = search", it'll give me the "cannot set property 'onclick' for null", even though there is a element id of 'btn' in the code.

So I changed it to 'onMouseDown = 'search()'', but although it does print out the test value of 5, it won't print out anything but null of 'searchBar', even though the value inside is automatically "Search...". Any idea about why this is happening?

Code:

```js
function setup(){
    initializeFirebase();
    var database = firebase.database();
    var featuredRef = database.ref("Featured/");
    var featured_ul = document.getElementById("featured_links");
    setupLunr(featuredRef, featured_ul);

    //var btn = document.getElementById(btn);
    //btn.onclick = search;
    //createServer();
}

function search(){
    console.log(5);
    var inputHandle = document.getElementById(searchBar);
    console.log(inputHandle.value);
    // var tag = inputHandle.value;
    // console.log(tag);
    // index.search(tag);
    //console.log(index.search(tag));
    // console.log(inputHandle);

}
```

```html
<body onload="setup()">
  <input type="text" id="searchBar" value="Search..." maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive();" /> 
  <button id="btn" onMouseDown="search();">Go</button>
  
  <h1>featured</h1>
  <ul id="featured_links"></ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you passing the correct strings to getElementById()?  Perhaps you are missing some double quotes? ... document.getElementById("btn")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not getting something like `Uncaught ReferenceError: searchBar is not defined(…)`, I can only assume 'searchBar' is defined somewhere and have some unrelated value in it.

Anyway you should change:

```
var inputHandle = document.getElementById(searchBar);
```

into

```
var inputHandle = document.getElementById("searchBar");
```

(Note the quotes)

EDIT: oh you were talking about btn. anyway its the same deal, it should be

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
```

unless 'btn' is a name of a var containing the id you want to find.

Comment: I hate my life. Thanks a bunch. Dumbest hour wasted ever